# Getting error '87 when trying to restore database SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2019

I'm running into an issue when trying to restore my database from a local .bak file, with the .mdf & .ldf files being located in my blob storage account in Azure Storage. The following is the error message I'm receiving (I've updated the URL parts to not include entire address):

```
Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The operating system returned the error '87(The parameter is incorrect.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'https://...........UAT.mdf'.
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
File 'ProductionSystem' cannot be restored to 'https://..........._UAT.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The operating system returned the error '87(The parameter is incorrect.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'https://.........._UAT_log.ldf'.
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
File 'ProductionSystem_log' cannot be restored to 'https://..........._UAT_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
```

I've checked the URL to make sure it's pulling from the correct URL address and that the spelling is correct throughout. And I haven't been able to find any other solutions only when it comes to restoring databases and getting error '87 in regards to mdf and ldf files.

I currently have a workaround by using a different test environment's mdf and ldf files and that looks to be working, but would like to get the problem files fixed.

Comment: Couple of things I would check, 1. The target has right write permissions, I assume you have it as your workaround was successful. 
2. The source where the back was taken can have different physical file location than target, if that is the case use WITH MOVE option to specify right target location where you need the restore to happen on target.